# update to php7.2 in docker wp-cli container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I'm new to docker. I have a WordPress stack for local dev that implements wp-cli via a different container. The WP container has PHP 7.2.4, but the wp-cli container appears to have php 5.6.27.

What's the best approach to updating php for wp-cli?

- remove wp-cli container, install wp-cli, save as a new container
- use a different container for wp-cli
- update php inside the existing container
- ?

snippets from my docker-compose file:

```
wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: jburger/wordpress-xdebug
    volumes:
      - "./public:/var/www/html"

 wpcli:
    command: "--info"
    container_name: wpcli
    entrypoint: wp
    image: tatemz/wp-cli
    links:
      - db:mysql
    volumes:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pulling in [an image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tatemz/wp-cli/tags/) which hasn't been freshly built/pushed in a year.

The DockerFile itself of these images is exactly what you need. If you clone the [original repo](https://github.com/tatemz/docker-wpcli) into a folder, set the build param in your docker-compose file to that folder, and then run `docker-compose build`, you'll have a fresh image.

The ideal setup is to actually have a 'workspace' container, which contains all of the tools needed to interact with your project, for a reference of what that looks like, see [laradock](http://laradock.io/) (it can be a bit overwhelming).

Comment: Is the reason that this image runs on 5.6 because it was built against a point in the WordPress container's history where it was running 5.6, and then php in the WP container was updated but the wp-cli image still sees the state of the filesystem as it was?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly right. It's not so much the state of the file system, as the image just not being rebuilt when 5.6 was the latest.